# SELECT usando php

Tags: php, html

Boa noite como atribuir um valor a uma variavel onde o valor vem do select? porém existem no formulario varios select, quero pegar o valor do select que esta selecionado.

Comment: No seu formulário existem vários selects ou um select com vários options? A pergunta não está bem formulada. Não sei como conseguiram responder! Veja na sua pergunta `porém existem no formulario varios select`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se entendi bem, você quer pegar valores de um `select multiple` lá do `form`, certo?

Neste caso deve-se interagir com `array` no php.

HTML:

```
<form action="pagina.php" method="GET"> 
 <select multiple name="select_multiple[]"> 
  <option value="Exemplo1">Exemplo1</option> 
  <option value="Exemplo2">Exemplo2</option> 
  <option value="Exemplo3">Exemplo3</option> 
  <option value="Exemplo4">Exemplo4</option> 
  <option value="Exemplo5">Exemplo5</option> 
 </select> 
</form>
```

PHP:

```
$select_multiple = $_GET['select_multiple'];
for ($i=0; $i < count($select_multiple); $i++){
    echo $select_multiple[$i];
}
```

Agora caso seja um `select` normal, o valor já vem setado da mesma forma que campos `text`, `checkbox`, `radio`, etc.

Comment: Era isso mesmo muito obrigada consegui fazer rodar o codigo